# How to downcast to [String: String] in a for in loop?

Tags: ios, json, swift, casting, nsdictionary

The [type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) section of the Swift programming language guide says it is possible to downcast in a for in loop when we know the item is of a certain type:

> Because this array is known to contain only Movie instances, you can
>   downcast and unwrap directly to a non-optional Movie with the forced
>   version of the type cast operator (as):

```
for movie in someObjects as [Movie] {
   println("Movie: '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
}
```

I am trying to do the same for my parsed JSON which has the following format:

```
{ "data":
   {"promotions": [ 
      { "id": "1", 
        "title": "Some promo",
        "route": "http://www.....jpg" 
      } , 
      { "id": "2",
        "title": "Promo 2",
        "route": "http://www.....jpg" 
      } ] 
   }
}
```

And my code:

```
if let data = json["data"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let promos = data["promotions"] as? NSArray {
        for i in promos as [String: String] { //<- error here
            if i["id"] != nil && i["title"] != nil && i["route"] != nil {
                self.promotions.append(Promotion(id: i["id"], title: i["title"], imageURL: i["route"]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this one shows an error: `'String' is not identical to 'NSObject'`. The JSON parses alright and I can use the items if I cast them individually, so this one works:

```
for i in promos {
    var item = i as [String: String]
    if item["id"] != nil && item["title"] != nil && item["route"] != nil {
        self.promotions.append(Promotion(id: item["id"]!, title: item["title"]!, imageURL: item["route"]!))
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Why I cannot cast the whole array in the `for...in`?

Comment: What's the need to downvote this question without any explanation? Some people...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast acts upon `promos` and not `i` in this case.  Since `promos` is an array of `[String: String]` dictionaries, you need to cast `promos` to `[[String: String]]`.  When you do this, `i` will have the type `[String: String]` since it is one element of the `[[String: String]]` array.

```
for i in promos as [[String: String]] {
```

Comment: I assumed it was the 'i' casted, but it is actually the array, of course... Thanks a lot!